# How do you monitor specific SQL statement of a specific user ?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, monitoring

We have a few standalone users here which cause high server loads for several 11.1.0.7 Oracle's. 
I spoke with them a few times but it seems that their queries are causing high loads and probably bottlenecks

Is there any option in Oracle to monitor or see which SQLs they running ? I'm not talking about only the ones which cause high loads, although they're the most important ones I would like to see all of their queries.

Comment: Are you running Enterprise Edition & do you have the diagnostic pack licensed?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look into [AUDIT ALL STATEMENTS BY user](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_4007.htm). As per Oracle's documentation, `audit all statements by ...`  *audits all **top-level SQL statements** executed. Top-level SQL statements are issued directly by a user. SQL statements run from within a PL/SQL procedure or function are not considered top-level statements. Therefore, this clause does not audit the statements executed within PL/SQL procedures or functions. However, the execution of the PL/SQL procedure or function itself is audited. This clause is useful if you want to audit all the statements in a specific environment, regardless of other auditing configurations that are system wide or user specific.*

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the quick answer but this does not answer my question :( I do not wish (or can...) limit those users, as they are special enough to have their own account to perform their own tests. The reason I wish to monitor their SQLs is because I can't speak with them every time they execute a killer SQL which blocks or makes the db high load.

Comment: I see. I have changed the answer accordingly.